Minimum expected number of 5-die rolls to simulate a fair 6-die
Context: If we only have a fair 5-sided die, we can emulate a fair 6-side die roll by rolling D5 twice. Out of 25 outcomes, we can map 24. If we get the 25th outcome, eg. (5,5), we just repeat the procedure. (I think it’s called rejection sampling?)
The expected number $E$ of rolls here is:
$$E = 2\times\frac{24}{25} + \frac{2+E}{25}$$
Hence
$$E = 25/12 = 2.08\overline{3}$$
Question: can we do better? I feel like we can’t, but I don’t know how to prove it.

If we are simply determining the expected number of rolls to reach our final number (a final result that is not $(5,5)$, I can think of two ways to model this:

That we roll both dice at once, and if the result is $(5,5)$, we roll both dice again, thus the number of dice rolled is 2 + double the number of times we've had to reroll.
That we roll the first die once, then roll the second die until the final result is not $(5,5)$, thus the total number of dice rolled is 2 + the number of times the second die is rerolled.

In the first case, each roll has a $\frac{1}{25}$ probability of rerolling, and a $\frac{24}{25}$ probability of reaching our target state. Thus, the expected number of dice thrown would be:
$$E(X)=2\times\left(1+\frac{1-\frac{24}{25}}{\frac{24}{25}}\right)=2 \times \left(1+\frac{1}{24}\right) = 2 \times \frac{25}{24}= 2.08\overline{3}$$
Which matches the expected value that you have calculated.
In the second case, the first die is never rerolled, and the second die can only be rerolled if the first die shows 5, in which case we roll the second die until 5 does not show (if the first die doesn't show five, the second die is never rerolled). In this case, The second die then follows a geometric distribution, with a $\frac{1}{5}$ probability of being rerolled, and a probability of hitting our target state being $\frac{4}{5}$. Thus, the expected number of dice thrown in this case should be:
$$E(X)=2+\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{1-\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{4}{5}}=2+\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{1}{4} = \frac{41}{20}=2.05$$
Which is indeed a lower expected number of rolls than our first option! However, it is worth noting that this option does not perfectly emulate a fair d6 - 4 of the 24 outcomes have a slightly higher probability than the rest:



d1 \ d2
1
2
3
4
5




1
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$


2
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$


3
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$


4
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$
$0.04$


5
$0.05$
$0.05$
$0.05$
$0.05$
$0$



Even with the fairest mapping possible, it is not possible to ensure that all 6 d6 outcomes have identical probability - at best, you can have 4 numbers with a probability of $0.17$ with the other two having a probability of $0.16$. This doesn't necessarily affect the expected value of our simulated d6  -  if we assign our two lower probabilities symmetrically (ie to 1 and 6, 2 and 5, or 3 and 4), then the Expected value of our simulated d6 is unchanged - it will still be $3.5$. However, if true fairness is required (ie all outcomes are equally likely), the second approach cannot be used.

The second option does not emulate a fair six-sided die, a condition that is implicitly required.

Huh. Yes, you're right, although with a decent mapping, you'd still be close to a uniform spread, with four numbers at $0.17$, and the other two at $0.16$. But if that is an implicit condition, than yes, the second option does not count. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Yeah, I meant a fair 6-die. The inspiration for the question was https://projecteuler.net/problem=863
